# Как может программа на python выводить рандомный результат на одних и тех же данных?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.6

Есть задание на pythontutor называется "Родословная: предки и потомки".

> Условие:
>   Даны два элемента в дереве. Определите, является ли один из них потомком другого.
>   Во входных данных записано дерево в том же формате, что и в предыдущей задаче Далее идет число запросов K. В каждой из следующих K строк, содержатся имена двух элементов дерева.
>   Для каждого такого запроса выведите одно из трех чисел: 1, если первый элемент является предком второго, 2, если второй является предком первого или 0, если ни один из них не является предком другого.

К ней даны вводные (src_data.txt):

```
9
Alexei Peter_I
Anna Peter_I
Elizabeth Peter_I
Peter_II Alexei
Peter_III Anna
Paul_I Peter_III
Alexander_I Paul_I
Nicholaus_I Paul_I
3
Anna Nicholaus_I
Peter_II Peter_I
Alexei Paul_I
```

Есть код (ну то-есть попытка решения):

```
def input():
    return rows.pop(0)

rows = []

file = open('src_data.txt', 'r')
for line in file:
    rows.append(line[:-1])
# ======== Досюда это имитация ввода на PythonTutor ===
names = set()
tree = []
for _ in range(int(input()), 1, -1):
    child, parrent = input().split()
    tree.append([child, parrent])
    names.update([child, parrent])
for name in names:
    for item in tree:
        if name == item[0]:
            for i in range(len(tree)):
                if name == tree[i][-1]:
                    tree[i].append(item[1])
# === Собственно проблема вот этом блоке (который выше) ==
# === Он то формирует списки как нужно, то недовставляет элементы ==

res_row = []
for _ in range(int(input())):
    pers_1, pers_2 = input().split()
    res = '0'
    for branch in tree:
        if pers_1 in branch and pers_2 in branch:
            if branch.index(pers_1) > branch.index(pers_2):
                res = '1'
            else:
                res = '2'
    res_row.append(res)
print(' '.join(res_row))
```

И все-бы ничего, если бы не рандомные значения в выводе:

```
for i in {1..40}; do python3 first.py; sleep 1; done
0 2 0
0 2 0
0 2 0
1 2 0
0 2 0
1 2 0
1 2 0
0 2 0
1 2 0
1 2 0
1 2 0
1 2 0
1 2 0
0 2 0
```

Объясните пожалуйста, как такое может быть и в чем ошибка?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<s>Собственно разобрался.
Блок который я отметил как проблемный сам по себе кривой, а рандомность результата от того, что у множества, которое задействовано в этом блоке сортировка отсутствует по определению и элементы расположены каждый раз по разному, соответственно цикл не до всех значений, как я понял, добирается и от того на каком месте в множестве находится элемент зависит вывод.</s>

Таки я ее добил (сам к разрабам не подсматривал) :-)).

```
def family(p: list, main_dict: dict):
    if p[-1] not in main_dict:
        return p
    return family(p + main_dict[p[-1]], main_dict)


ancestors = {x: [y] for x, y in [input().split() for _ in range(int(input()) - 1)]}


for child, parent in ancestors.items():
    ancestors[child] = family(ancestors[child], ancestors)

for child, parent in ancestors.copy().items():
    if parent[0] not in ancestors:
        ancestors[parent[0]] = ancestors.get(parent[0], list())

relatives = []
for _ in range(int(input())):
    kinsman_1, kinsman_2 = input().split()
    if kinsman_1 in ancestors[kinsman_2]:
        relatives.append(1)
    elif kinsman_2 in ancestors[kinsman_1]:
        relatives.append(2)
    else:
        relatives.append(0)

print(*relatives)
```

Answer (score 1):

Не забывайте после file=open(***) сделать file.close()
И, кстати, в этой задаче нужно использовать рекурсию. Я сам достаточно давно пытался решить эту задачу тоже на pythontutor, сделал очень длинное и страшное решение(безо всякой рекурсии естественно)) ) и оно сработало на всех вариантах pythontutor, потом разбирался в том решении, которое предоставил мне pythontutor) Сложная задача по мне.

Comment: У меня, если честно мозг вспух от этой задачи.

Comment: Вот вот, я тоже с распухшей головой сидел, после кучи попыток решения) Задача непростая