# Получение результата скрипта из другого Python скрипта

Tags: python, python-3.x

Мне нужно получить результат выполнение одного скрипта из другого. Мне надо именно не выполнить нужный скрипт из другого, а получить, то что он выведет в консоль и записать в другую переменную. Например у меня есть скрипт Script1.py, который проводит какие-то вычисления и полученный результат в итоге содержится в переменной result. Как я могу из другого скрипта(Script2.py) получить значение переменной result и продолжить с ним работать. Я пробовал способ

```
sys.system(Script1.py)
```

но он просто выполняет Script1.py, а мне нужно именно получить результат, который он выводит в консоль(или значение переменной из этого скрипта), а не вывести результат в консоль.

Способ:

```
p = subprocess.Popen("python Script1.py arg1 arg2", stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
```

Выдает объект Popen, но я не знаю, что с ним делать

Как я могу из одного скрипта получить результат другого? В каком направлении искать? Заранее спасибо за любую оказанную помощь.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В строке

```
p = subprocess.Popen("python Script1.py arg1 arg2", stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
```

укажите полный путь до файла `Script1.py`

В принципе эта процедура должна выглядеть так:

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE
out, err = Popen('python3 /full/path/to/Script1.py', shell=True, stdout=PIPE).communicate()
print(str(out, 'utf-8')) # или var = str(out, 'utf-8')
```

> Исходя из тега `python-3.x` в вопросе, полагаю, что в строке `subprocess.Popen("python Script1.py arg1 arg2", stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)` Вам стоит дописать тройку к `python`

Comment: Не обязательно было указывать полный путь. Обычно, без конкретной нужды(если, например, файл с нужной программой не лежит в той же директории с исполняемым скриптом) это не требуется                               Ваш способ мне помог. Большое спасибо!

Comment: Вы не знаете как в программу передать аргументы на нескольких строках? То есть мне нужно ввести команду, сымитировав как-будто пользователь ввел в cmd название команды, нажал Enter, потом ввел несколько аргументов, после каждого нажав Enter. То есть внутри программы идет ввод через input(), а мне эти инпуты нужно при вызове на отдельных строках программе скормить. То есть команда должна быть следующая - "python Script1.py \n arg1 \n arg2" Вот только если передать данную команду, то судя по всему она воспринимается как одна строка и интерпретатор ждет ввода, хотя я его и хотел передать

Comment: А вы каким IDE пользуетесь? Обычно в настройках проекта есть эта опция, переадресации input(). Если у Вас нет, то сейчас поищу, здесь где-то в одном из моих вопросов была эта реализация костыльным методом

Comment: Использую Sublime Text, но все-таки очень хотелось бы именно на уровне языка научиться это делать, а не зависеть от конкретного IDE. Поищите пожалуйста, я уже замучился искать как это исполнить(благо как перехватить вывод программы вы меня уже научили) ) Осталось только ввод в скрипт исполнить

Comment: Посмотрите [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/876341/295125). Там в вопросе код в коде это реализовано буквально 5-6 верхних строк (они отмечены как `имитация ввода pythontutor`. А вообще добрый Вам совет, слезайте с саблайма, на python в саблайме писать очень не удобно. Могу порекомендовать бесплатный `PyCharm community`. Там и дебагер нормальный и фитчи специальные имеются, без плясок с бубном

Comment: Я как раз и хочу сделать имитацию ввода как на pythontutor) Насчет совета - спасибо, посмотрю на различные среды разработки. А чем вам Sublime не нравится?

Comment: @FedotSoldier, Он мне очень нравится, и до того как начал мучать Python, я только в нем и писал. Но для Python не получилось у меня его настроить, так, чтобы было комфортно. А вот PyCharm, можно сказать, прям "из коробки" зашел.

Comment: Ну с этим есть небольшие заморочки типа настроек build system под разные языки, но мне сейчас вполне на нем комфортно. Мне просто пока громоздкие среды разработки не особо необходимы. Но вообще ладно, присмотрю себе что-нибудь более мощное чем блокнот на всякий случай

Comment: А, чтобы просто команду из cmd выполнить с помощью Popen - это Popen('python Script1.py') - просто как в командной строке команда? Ничего больше выполнять не надо, аргументов передавать других не требуется, скрипт просто выполнится и все?

Comment: @FedotSoldier, Не знаю как в винде, но в лине если первой строкой кода поставить шебанг `!#/usr/bin/env python3` ну или без тройки как у кого настроено, и сделать файл исполняемым, то можно просто  `Script1.py`

Comment: Ну у меня windows, ладно, еще раз спасибо за помощь. Сейчас перехват вывода в своем скрипте переделаю и буду смотреть вашу ссылку с решением по поводу ввода

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/84792/discussion-between-andrey-and-fedotsoldier).

Answer (score 0):

У меня есть 2 идеи как это сделать

1. один из скриптов сделать функцией, который будет возвращать обработанные данные, путём return .
   Далее в другом скрипте необходимо импортировать первый скрипт (скрипты должны находиться в 1 папке), путём import <название скрипта без .py>. Получить результат работы теперь очень просто, нужно лишь переменной во втором скрипте присвоить значение из 1 скрипта (from_second = doInFirst() )
2. сохранить результат работы скрипта в текстовый файл, а затем прочитать его в другом скрипте
   В первом скрипте

````
file.write("то что у тебя получилось")
file.close()```

Во втором скрипте
```file = open(path, 'r', encoding="UTF-8")
a = file.read()
file.close()```

Заметь, что для 2 способа необходимо либо держать скрипты в 1 папке, либо знать абсолютный путь до создаваемого файла
````